# android: activities don't display anything with sidebar navigation drawer

Tags: android, scala, android-layout

Well I have created a sidebar navigation drawer activity and trying to use it as a parent class in order to use it in all activities. So, I am extending this drawer class in all activities. Now if I do that, those activities don't display anything, just a blank page. Doesn't matter what I have in those activities. Here is the structure of my application:

For the navigation drawer I have:-

```
left_drawer.xml (layout for the drawer)
navigation_header.xml (header for the drawer)
navigation_menu.xml (to populate the drawer menu)
LeftDrawerMenuActivity.class (drawer class)
```

Other activity (main):-

```
main.xml (main activity layout)
MainActivity.class (main activity class)
```

Now I am extending the `LeftDrawerMenuActivity` class in main activity. `LeftDrawerMenuActivity` extends the `AppComaptActivity` class.

Note: I am using Scala to build the app.

Comment: Instead of creating activities and extend MainActivity(DrawerActivity) create fragments for each menu items and single activity can holds number of fragments.

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH : Sorry for late reply. Can you please write an answer with a sample code with two classes ( one is the drawer activity itself and the other will be some activity which uses the drawer) ?